# Google GCS to BIGQUERY fails when bringing in whole rows of data (via airflow)

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am using a GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator with the intent to bringing a whole series of similarly structured files into big query.

Because I know the files will need to be parsed in bigquery due to limitations of ingestion, I want to bring in each row of data as a single data element (one field).  Below is my code:

```
GCS_to_GBQ_Raw = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='GCS_to_GBQ_Raw',
    bucket='files',
    source_objects=['To_Process/*.csv'],
    source_format='CSV',
    destination_project_dataset_table='DS.RAW',
    schema_fields=[
       {'name': 'datarow', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
    ],
    field_delimiter='\t',
    autodetect=False,
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    quote_character='µ',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='GCP_Staging',
    bigquery_conn_id='GCP_Staging',
    dag=dag)
```

I have tried the following:

1. field_delimiter - I have tried obscure ascii characters such the section character, pipes, and tabs.  I know the data in the files have none of these.
2. autodetect=True and False.
3. quote_character='', '""', the current character mu, and other characters I know are not in the file.

I get a random group of errors each time I run:

- Too many columns
- Data between quote and end of field
- trying to append

How do I make this work?  how do I bring in the rows, complete, so I can parse them in bq?

Thanks!

Comment: So, your BQ table would have only a single column which will consist all the data from a row in the file?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how your files look and if you can provide some sample records then we can be of better help.
If i have understood your problem correctly then the below code should work:

```
import datetime as dt
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
# from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
lasthour = dt.datetime.utcnow() - dt.timedelta(hours=1)

args = {
 'owner': 'airflow',
 'start_date': lasthour,
 'depends_on_past': False,
 'job_name': 'employee-test',
}
dag = DAG(
 dag_id='just-check',
 schedule_interval=None,
 default_args=args
)

load_csv = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bq_example',
    bucket='testing-bucket',
    source_objects=['employee/*.csv'],
    field_delimiter='|',
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    autodetect=False,
    destination_project_dataset_table='project_id.raw.gcs_to_bq_table',
    schema_fields=[
       {'name': 'datarow', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
    ],
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    dag=dag)
```

After running this DAG, my BQ table had one column for each row of the data.

Comment: that actually did it.  the file was pushing random characters that the field_delimiter was detecting....I had to scour it to find them.  Thanks much